# Solving a large system of linear equations to satisfy the Lie bracket: am I doing it right?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm still working on a Lie algebra isomorphism from the Lie algebra of $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ into the Lie algebra of $O(3, \mathbb C)$.

[It has been suggested to me to use linear combinations of coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129982/defining-an-isomorphism-that-respects-the-lie-bracket-is-my-work-correct#comment2309001_1130003) but I'm not sure what I'm doing is right since I got that all coefficients are equal to zero. Of course they are not all zero since the resulting map wouldn't be an isomorphism.

> Please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Let $b_1,b_2,b_3$ be the basis of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and $B_1,B_2,B_3$ the basis of $\mathfrak o$:

$$ b_1 = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } b_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, b_3 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}  $$

and a basis for $\mathfrak o$ is given by

$$ B_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, B_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix},  B_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

so that

$(\ast)$ $[b_1,b_2]=b_3, [b_1,b_3]=-2b_1$, $[b_2,b_3]=2b_2$ and

$(\ast \ast)$ $[B_1,B_2]=B_3, [B_1,B_3]=-B_2, [B_2,B_3]=B_1$.

If $\varphi: \mathfrak{sl}_2\to \mathfrak o$ denotes the isomorphism $(\ast)$ translates into the following equations we want to satisfy:

$$ [\varphi(b_1),\varphi(b_2)]=\varphi(b_3)$$

$$ [\varphi(b_1),\varphi(b_3)]=-2\varphi(b_1) $$

$$[\varphi(b_2),\varphi(b_3)]=2\varphi(b_2)$$

Representing the image using the following coefficients

$$\varphi(b_1) = a_1 B_1 + a_2 B_2 + a_3 B_3$$
$$\varphi(b_2) = c_1 B_1 + c_2 B_2 + c_3 B_3$$
$$\varphi(b_3) = d_1 B_1 + d_2 B_2 + d_3 B_3$$

and using that the bracket is bilinear and that $[x,x]=0$ and that $[x,y]=-[y,x]$ and the equation $(\ast \ast)$ I got the following system of equations:

$$ [\varphi(b_1),\varphi(b_2)] = (a_1 c_2 - a_2 c_1)B_3 + (a_1 c_3 - a_3c_1)(-B_2) + (a_2 c_3 - a_3 c_2)B_1 = varphi(b_3) = d_1 B_1 + d_2 B_2 + d_3 B_3$$

$$ (a_1d_2 - a_2d_1)B_3 + (a_1d_3 - a_3 d_1)(-B_2) + (a_2 d_3 - a_3 d_2)B_1 = -2(a_1B_1+a_2B_2+a_3B_3) $$

$$(c_1d_2 - c_2d_1)B_3 + (c_1d_3 - c_3d_1)(-B_2) + (c_2d_3 - c_3d_2)B_1 = 2(c_1B_1 + c_2B_2 + c_3B_3)$$

Then I sorted the equations into three systems $"B_1", "B_2" , "B_2"$ like e.g. "B_1":

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
a_2c_3 &- a_3 c_2 &- d_1 & = &0\\
a_2 d_3 &-a_3d_2 &+ 2a_1 &=&0\\
c_2d_3 &-c_3d_2 &-2c_1 &= &0
\end{array}$$

(I'm omitting the other two to avoid making the question too long)

Then I collected the second equation in each of the three systems to get

$$ \begin{pmatrix}2&d_3&-d_2\\ -d_3&2 &d_1\\ d_2 & -d_1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3\end{pmatrix}=0$$

and using the third rows

$$ \begin{pmatrix}-2&d_3&-d_2\\ -d_3&-2 &d_1\\ d_2 & -d_1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3\end{pmatrix}=0$$

From which I deduced $a_1 = - c_1, a_2 = -c_2, a_3 = -c_3$. I substituted this into the first equation of each system which resulted in $d_1=d_2=d_3 =0$ from which it follows that all the coefficients are zero.

I put a lot of work into finding this isomorphism already and I'd appreciate any help towards finding it.

Comment: I think one of the basis element commutators is wrong: We should have $[B_2, B_3] = B_1$.

Comment: @Travis Thank you! Let me check.

Comment: @Travis It was just a typo I made in the question. Here on paper I didn't make this mistake. I will edit the question, thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your method looks sound, but the conclusion $a_1=-c_1$, $a_2=-c_2$, $a_3=-c_3$ is wrong. The matrices being multiplied by the $a$'s and $c$'s are not opposites: they are opposite along the main diagonal but the same off it. So the $a$'s and $c$'s won't be opposite.

Addendum: by your method, you should arrive at equations that any correct isomorphism (or actually any lie algebra homomorphism) would satisfy, but you should not expect your equations to have *unique* solutions. $\mathfrak{o}$ has many isomorphisms to itself (for example, for any fixed $P\in O(3,\mathbb{C})$, the map $X\mapsto PXP^{-1}$ is an isomorphism of $\mathfrak{o}$ to itself), so there will be many isomorphisms from $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ to $\mathfrak{o}$, and thus your equations will have many solutions.